# link to products belonging to more than one category in prestashop?

Tags: hyperlink, categories, prestashop

Ive got a category structure like this:

Category 1

- Category 2
- Category 3

Category 4

- Category 5
- Category 6

Category 7

Category 8

And wanna show all the products that belong to Category 8 AND Category 3. Category 8 is not a child of 3.

How can I do it? How (first of all) can I build the relative link?

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to achieve this, however in terms of performance it mostly depends on the size of your catalog.

Here is an example written in SQL that would be very fast and also make sure the selected products are active:

```
$products_categories = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
SELECT cp.id_product, pl.name product_name
FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product cp
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'category c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p ON (p.id_product = cp.id_product)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = p.id_product)
WHERE cp.id_category = 3 AND p.active = 1 AND c.active = 1 and pl.id_lang = 1 AND cp.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product WHERE id_category = 8)');
```

Comment: Ah ok, a subquery. Yess, could be. I never considered it since I'm not very smart in SQL :P Thank you!
And then? I'm quite new to prestashop, therefore a lot of worries are spinning in my head.. I was wandering, you mean I would build a new Controller and pass $products_categories to $smarty? That would be quite simple, but would it be safe then, with subsequent actions (ex. add to cart the products, further filter with blocklayered module, etc..)? I mean, is it a common practice?